# Query involving parent and child objects in where, group by and order by clause

Tags: soql, query, dynamic-soql, sosl

I have an object called SRC which has account as lookup in it. SRC content will be as shown below:

| SRC ID | Account__c | Status | City__c | LastModifiedOn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Yes | Delhi | 12-Apr |
| 2 | 1 | No | Cochin | 13-Apr |
| 3 | 2 | No | Delhi | 14-Apr |
| 4 | 2 | Yes | Indore | 15-Apr |

SRC is created populating the BillingCity from Account at that point of time. So everytime BillingCity is changed in account there will be a new SRC created.

I want latest SRC record of an account. The output is as shown below:

| SRC ID | Account__c | Status | City__c | LastModifiedOn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | No | Cochin | 13-Apr |
| 4 | 2 | Yes | Indore | 15-Apr |

I ideally want to write a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    Status 
FROM SRC__c 
WHERE 
    Account__c IN ('1', '2') AND 
    Account__r.BillingCity = City__c
GROUP BY Account__r.Id 
ORDER by LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

How can I achieve this? I cannot run the query inside a for loop, because I am writing this code in a trigger.

I have two problems here:

1. Account__r.BillingCity = City__c is not allowed
2. using group by gives me "Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated" error

Comment: In what context are you trying to add a query? Is this a trigger on Account that updates SRCs? Or is this a trigger on SRC?

Comment: Actually, it is trigger on quote. I want to see if the latest account's SRC status is "Yes".

Answer (score 1):

If you query `FROM Account`, you can order the child records. This grouping strategy will be much easier to work with here.

```
SELECT (SELECT Status__c FROM SRCs__r ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC)
FROM Account WHERE ...
```

Make sure you get the correct child relationship name. There are numerous posts [both](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/19459/2995) [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/140929/2995) [and](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/167933/2995) in the Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_custom_objects.htm) on how to do so.

Comment: My SRC object has lookup to Account, but Account does not have relationship to SRC. In this case, how can I write this query?

Comment: A child relationship _is_ a relationship. You described your relationships the same in your original post, and this answer covers how to query in that situation...